# send data from one activity's button click event to the another activity's edittext which is in background

Tags: android

there are two activities act1 and act2, in act1 there is one edittext and act2 there is one button.
When I click on act1's edittext then act2 should open and then after when i click on button of act2 then
text "hello" should be displayed in edittext of act1.
How to do this please help..

I need not to use Intent for data sending.

Note: Please Read and understand completely before marking this post as duplicate.

Comment: Try to take one static flag in act1 and when act2 button click set as true and try to check this flag in onResume() and show "hello" base flag value in act1.

Comment: Thanks for answer, i want live changing my act2 is semi transperent so change in text should be visible live in act1 how to do this.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Edit:**

Create a static method and a static variable in `Activity1`:

```
public class Activity1 extends Activity {

    static TextView mTextView;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

        ...

        mTextView = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.textView);
    }

    public static void setText(String text) {
        if (mTextView != null) {
            mTextView.setText(text);
        }
    }
}
```

Then after you started the `Activity1` call `setText` from wherever:

```
Activity1.setText("hello");
```

Comment: Thanks for answer, i want live changing my act2 is semi transperent so change in text should be visible live in act1 how to do this.

Comment: @AnuragRabadia why didn't you add this crucial information to your question? Anyways.. I have edited my answer.